# Python. Как список вывести в столбик? если он получился очень длинным

Tags: python, list

Мне нужно чтобы через определенное количество элементов выводилась с новой строки.

```
table = [[x * y for x in range(1, 6)] for y in range(1, 6)]
print(table)
```

Примерно так:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
 [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
 [4, 8, 12, 16, 20],
 [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примените стандартный модуль [`pprint`](https://digitology.tech/docs/python_3/library/pprint.html) и его функцию с тем же самым названием, `pprint()`:

```
import pprint

...
pprint.pprint(table)
```

или - с тем же самым результатом -

```
from pprint import pprint

...
pprint(table)
```

*Вывод:*

> ```
> [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
>  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
>  [3, 6, 9, 12, 15],
>  [4, 8, 12, 16, 20],
>  [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]]
> ```

*Примечание:*

`pprint` значит *«pretty print»*, **«красивая печать»**.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант - через loop:

```
table = [[x * y for x in range(1, 6)] for y in range(1, 6)]
for i in table:
    print(i)
```